# Как понять условие задачи?

Tags: java, массивы, алгоритм

Есть такое условие задачи:

> Consider the leftmost and righmost appearances of some value in an
>   array. We'll say that the "span" is the number of elements between the
>   two inclusive. A single value has a span of 1. Returns the largest
>   span found in the given array. (Efficiency is not a priority.)

Примеры входных и соответствующих им выходных данных:

> maxSpan([1, 2, 1, 1, 3]) → 4
>
> maxSpan([1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 1, 4]) → 6
>
> maxSpan([1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 4, 4]) → 6

Не могу понять условие задачи. Не могу понять, что такое "span".

Comment: Похоже нужно найти наибольшое количество элементов между двумя одинаковыми. maxSpan([**1, 2, 1, 1**, 3]), maxSpan([1, **4, 2, 1, 4, 4, 4**])

Comment: Размах, диапазон. В вашем варианте - максимум для разности индексов крайнего справа вхождения и крайнего левого, +1. В первом случае для 2 и 3 получаем 1, для 1 - индекс правой единицы - 3, левой - 0, итого - 3-0+1=4. Для второго: для 1 - 5-1+1=5, для 2 - 2-2+1=1, для 4 - 6-1+1=6. Максимальное среди этих значений - 6.

Comment: @Harry прав. К примеру, для последнего варианта, индекс первого вхождения "4" - [1], последнего вхождения - [6], 6 - 1  + 1 = 6.

Answer (score 1):

Если взять какое нибудь значение массива, которое появляется первый раз слева и даллее смотрим, его последнее появление справа, то span - это подмассив, получающийся после екстракта элементом между этими двумя элементами включая эти  элементы, а длина этого массива представляет размер спана. Так вот задача для разных значений элементов данного массива вычислить максимальный размер спана.

Если вы хотите понять, почему получаются такие значения, то вам надо найти такой элемент у которого спан максимальный. Например

```
maxSpan([1, 2, 1, 1, 3]) → 4 //елемент 1

maxSpan([1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 1, 4]) → 6 //елемент 1

maxSpan([1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 4, 4]) → 6 //елемент 4
```

Comment: *"span" is the* **number** *of elements* - т.е. это никак не подмассив, но его размер...